# Widget Windows - consume Web Service REST with JSON response

Tags: javascript, web-services, web, windows-desktop-gadgets

I implement a gadget windows and I can call a REST Web Service. I have search on many topic in google and in stackoverflow, but I haven't fund the solution of my problem.

I want to use an ajax call, but it doesn't work, the "$" isn't defined.

My code :

```
function callWebService(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"url",
    data:'arguments',
    dataType:"json",
    success : function(msg){
        loadJSON(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert("Error : " + msg);
    }
});
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ is not defined because jquery is not present in that client.

Comment: Thx, I have check and the jQuerry version was the minify version. With the complet version of jQuerry, I have no problem.